# Alternative to splitapply in Matlab

Tags: matlab, split-apply-combine

I am trying to run someone else's Matlab code that uses the [`splitapply` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html), which is only available in R2018a. I am currently using R2015a; is there a simple (albeit less efficient) alternative implementation which achieves the same purpose that could be used (temporarily)?

Answer (score 3):

The documented `splitapply` usage also relies on `findgroups`. Both of these were implemented in R2015b<sup>[1]</sup>.

You can use the third output of `unique` in place of `findgroups`, and a simple loop in place of `splitapply`. Here is an example which assumes `data` is a column vector, you could easily adapt this to work for matrix data.

```
% With splitapply
g = findgroups( data );           
m = splitapply( @mean, data, g ); % Your function in place of mean here

% Without splitapply (pre-R2015b)
[~, ~, g] = unique( data ); % Get group indices
m = zeros(max(g), 1);       % Initialise the output matrix
for ii = 1:max(g)
    m(ii) = mean( data( g == ii ) ); % Your function in place of mean here
end
```

With some quick tests, I find these methods comparable for speed on reasonable size arrays. For ~100 groups and ~1e6 elements in `data` I find that the loop method is up to 4x slower, but still pretty quick.

---

<sup>[1] Note: the MathWorks documentation defaults to the most recent release, which is why you thought `splitapply` was introduced in R2018a. At the bottom of each function's doc page though, it states when it was introduced. In the case of `splitapply`, we see "Introduced in R2015b".</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `splitapply` has been introduced in R2015b.

Anywaym as described in the [splitapply](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) documentation, the function [combines two steps in the Split-Apply-Combine Workflow](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html#bux1l61)

The following picture (from the `splitapply` on-line documentation describes the process:

[image]

Basically `splitapply` uses the function [findgroups](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) to group the input data, then it applies a function to each group of data.

UNfortunately for you, also `findgroups` has been introduced in R2015b therefore the main issue is to find a way to implement it.

To implement a "general" version of `findgroups` might require lots of time in order to enable it to work on several different type of dataset.

Just to begin you can start implementing it in a form matching the specific dataset you have to work with.

Basically, you can implement a semplified version of it by using the [unique](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function.

The idea is to use it in order to retrieve:

- the list of unique entries in the dataset: these will be the *groups*
- the indices of the entries in the dataset corresponding to those groups

Once you have the indices of the groups in the dataset, you can use them to downselect the values of the dataset and to use them as input for the function you need to apply.

In the following you can find an example of a possible implementation which reproduces the example provided in the on-line helpo of `splitapply`.

Of course this is not a "general" implementation working with "every" dataset, actually it works for the specific input of the example, but,I hope, it could be a starting point.

**On-line example of splitapply**

[Excerpt of the on-line documentation](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html#buy18_o)

```
load patients
meanBMIFcn = @(h,w)mean((w ./ (h.^2)) * 703);
DT = table(Height,Weight);
GT = table(Gender,Smoker);
[G,results] = findgroups(GT);
meanBMI = splitapply(meanBMIFcn,DT,G);
results.meanBMI = meanBMI
```

**Output**

```
results=4×3 table
     Gender     Smoker    meanBMI
    ________    ______    _______

    'Female'    false     21.672 
    'Female'    true      21.669 
    'Male'      false     26.578 
    'Male'      true      26.458
```

**A possible implementation**

```
clear w

% Find the unique entries in the first dataset
[uni_list_1,~,uni_idx_1]=unique(Gender)
n_group_1=length(uni_list_1)

% Find the unique entries in the second dataset
[uni_list_2,~,uni_idx_2]=unique(Smoker)
n_group_2=length(uni_list_2)

% Get the indices of the occurrencies of the combinatin of the two
% entities
for g1=1:length(uni_list_1)
   for g2=1:length(uni_list_2)
      data_set.(uni_list_1{g1}).(['cond_' num2str(uni_list_2(g2))])=(uni_idx_1 == g1) & (uni_idx_2 == g2)
   end
end

% Define the function to be applied
meanBMIFcn = @(h,w)mean((w ./ (h.^2)) * 703);

% Extract the data matching the desired conditions and use them as input to
% the disired function
for g1=1:length(uni_list_1)
   for g2=1:length(uni_list_2)
      height=Height(data_set.(uni_list_1{g1}).(['cond_' num2str(uni_list_2(g2))]));
      weight=Weight(data_set.(uni_list_1{g1}).(['cond_' num2str(uni_list_2(g2))]));
      result.data_set.(uni_list_1{g1}).(['cond_' num2str(uni_list_2(g2))])=meanBMIFcn(height,weight)
   end
end
```

**Output**

The output is in form of struct whose fields are the groups and the additional condition

```
>> result
result = 
    data_set: [1x1 struct]
>> result.data_set
ans = 
    Female: [1x1 struct]
      Male: [1x1 struct]
>> result.data_set.Female
ans = 
    cond_0: 21.6721
    cond_1: 21.6686
>> result.data_set.Male
ans = 
    cond_0: 26.5775
    cond_1: 26.4584
```

Comment: Hi il_raffa. I am a volunteer editor here, and one of the things editors sometimes do is to trim posts for brevity. I notice that you have hoped your contributions help 111 times, but this can rather be taken for granted, on the basis that no-one posts hoping their work does not help. The alternative is that the many millions of answers on the site could have this string appended to them, but since that would be redundant, we say that the site is better off without them. We're the same with signatures too, and in fact I think the Help Centre specifically asks people not to sign their posts.

Comment: Thus, if you could refrain from adding these things in the future, that would be great - it would slightly reduce the workload for volunteers, who already have a lot of work to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [grpstats](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/grpstats.html) from the *statistics* toolbox.

[image]